# swift uiwebview is nil

Tags: ios, webview

some disapointement with uiwebview, for very simple code

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mavue: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        mavue?.loadRequest(request)
        println("myWebView :  \(mavue)")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

println("myWebView :  (mavue)") return nil

i try it on simulator, i have loaded my controllerview from presentViewController maybe it's the reason why?
but my code doesn't show mywebview.
mywebView is connected to my IBoutlet
thank

EDIT : It 's work, I think that th mistake was to keep the default uiviewcontroller , when i use a subclass all is ok

Thank

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4lfkonbjrcque8/webView.zip?dl=0

Comment: It 's work, I think that th mistake was to keep the default uiviewcontroller , when i use a subclass all is ok THANK